# Problem with Integration involving Logarithmic and Exponential Functions

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

We have tried to determine the following integration problem.

$\displaystyle\int_0^k \, dx \, \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1 - (x/k)^2}} \, \ln\left[1 - e^{-x/t}\right] \quad k,\, t>0$

It would be very helpful if someone can help us to solve it.

Also I would like to know, if we cannot solve a definite integration problem analytically, then what other techniques can possibly be used? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps tanh sinh quadrature to deal with singularities. Note integrals 7 and 8. http://crd-legacy.lbl.gov/~dhbailey/dhbpapers/quadrature.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting integral.

For the moment, let's just rewrite it in a different way by simply unifying the denominator:

$$\int_0^k \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{\frac{k^2 - x^2}{k^2}}} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x/t}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

A little algebra leads you to

$$k\int_0^k \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{k^2 - x^2}} \ln\left(1 - e^{-x/t}\right)\ \text{d}x$$

Now let's perform a change of variable:

$$x = k\sin\theta ~~~~~ \text{d}x = k\cos\theta$$

Hence you get

$$k\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{k^2\sin^2\theta}{\sqrt{k^2(1- \sin^2\theta)}} \ln\left(1 - e^{-k\sin\theta/t}\right)\ k\cos\theta \text{d}\theta$$

Which becomes easily

$$k^3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \ln\left(1 - e^{-\alpha\sin\theta}\right)\ \text{d}\theta$$

Where $\alpha = k/t$.

**First try, with approximation**

Assuming the term $\alpha$ is large enough (not guaranteed, but as I said it's an approximation just to see what happens), we may think of a series expansion for the EXP up to the second order (cut):

$$e^{-\alpha\sin\theta} \approx 1 - \alpha\sin\theta$$

Hence

$$k^3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \ln\left(1 - (1 - \alpha\sin\theta)\right)\ \text{d}\theta$$

$$k^3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \ln\left(\alpha\sin\theta\right)\ \text{d}\theta$$

Due to the log properties, $\log(\alpha\sin\theta) = \log\alpha + \log\sin\theta$ and we spit into two integrals

$$(1) ~~~~~~~ k^3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \ln(\alpha)\ \text{d}\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}k^3\ln(\alpha)$$

$$(2) ~~~~~~~ k^3\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^2\theta \ln\left(\sin\theta\right)\ \text{d}\theta = -\frac{\pi}{8}k^3 (\ln(4)-1)$$

Hence **in this case** the solution would be

$$\frac{k^3\pi}{4}\left[\ln\left(\frac{k}{t}\right) - \frac{1}{2}\ln(4) + \frac{1}{2}\right]$$

**Questions**

Is that approximation valid? Well, yes and no. It all depends on the ratio $k/t$, and of course on how much we go on with the Taylor Series for the EXP.

Another way would be to use the Series for the entire LOG function, you may try.

Notice that in another very special case

$$k = t = 1$$

You get the same answer

$$-0.460655$$

**Second order approximation**

Just in case you want to go on, you'd have

$$e^{-\alpha\sin\theta} \approx 1 - \alpha\sin\theta + \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\sin^2\theta + \ldots$$

Hence the log would become

$$\ln\left(1 - \left(1 - \alpha\sin\theta + \frac{\alpha^2}{2}\sin^2\theta\right)\right) = \ln\left(\alpha\sin\theta\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\theta\right)\right)$$

Which is again split into

$$\ln(\alpha\sin\theta) + \ln\left(1 - \frac{\alpha}{2}\sin\theta\right)$$

Integration of those terms would, this time, be not so easy. Indeed, except the first term which is easy the new second one is given in terms of Hypergeometric functions. You would have indeed **at the second order**

$$\frac{\pi}{8}\left(2 - \frac{9}{4}\ln(4) + \frac{8}{3\pi}\frac{k}{t} + 2\ln\left(\frac{k}{t}\right)\right) -\frac{1}{45} (k/t)^3 \, _3F_2\left(1,\frac{3}{2},3;\frac{5}{2},\frac{7}{2};\frac{(k/t)^2}{4}\right)+\frac{\pi  \left(\sqrt{4-(k/t)^2}-2\right)}{2 (k/t)^2}+\frac{1}{4} \pi  \log \left(\sqrt{4-(k/t)^2}+2\right)$$

This is what I could do for the moment.

Integrals of this type I guess they can be solved (if possible) only via numerical methods, approximations or other ways, but not analytically.

Anyway I'll think more about.

More on Hypergeometric Functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function